# Drawing a graph on torus and projective plane.

Tags: graph-theory, projective-geometry

Do You know any tool where I can "draw" a graph on torus and projective plane? (I want to draw there without intersections graphs which are not planar on R^2). I mean drawing like in Paint, not by programming (Im too weak for that).

Of course I can copy prewritten code by better people than me command to draw a torus on i. e. SageMath, but there is no way I draw a graph on it by programming.

Answer (score 2):

Try [chameleon.js](https://github.com/tomtung/chameleon.js#chameleonjs)  Read the instructions, follow [the link](https://tomtung.github.io/chameleon.js/), find a torus obj file ([like here](https://github.com/pyramation/GLQuery/blob/master/models/Torus.obj)), download it and drag and drop it into the browser window and start painting.  You can adjust paintbrush size and color, etc.